# the app references non-public selectors in Payload - App Store Connect Operation Error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode14

I have tried to upload two of my apps to Apple store, but I have got bellow errors on the "App Store Connect Operation Error" Screen

> 1. the app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails:
> 2. The app references non-public selectors in Payload/.app/: setConsent:

My Xcode version is 14.2 . I did not change the source code and trying to update my current app's version for AppStore. I tried to investigate the issue but can't find a solution. Any help?

Comment: The error message is clear. Your app has illegal code. What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it is google admob pod issue. I have updated version of Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK from 8.4.0 to 8.12.0 inside PodFile, then pod update Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK. The Error is gone

Comment: I may add that I also needed to remove leftover iAd frameworks `libAdapterIAd` and `iAd.framework` from my build target if above is not enough.